# Array does not fill correctly when optimization is enabled GCC ARM

Tags: c, arrays, optimization, gcc

I have code that works great to populate an array from values of a linked list without optimization.  Once I enable optimization (-02) the first value in the array loads correctly but all the subsequent values appear incorrect (invalid memory range).

```
typedef struct lineInfo_s lineInfo_t;

struct lineInfo_s{
    unsigned short * lineBuffer;
    volatile lineInfo_t * next;
    volatile lineInfo_t * prev;
};

static unsigned char blankLine[72];     //Use this when no entry in linked list


static void foo(lineInfo_t * lineAddr) {
    unsigned char * lines[6];

    bool noNext = lineAddr->next==0UL;
    bool noNextNext = true;

    if(!noNext) noNextNext = (lineAddr->next)->next==0UL;
    ...
    //Load the Array
    lines[0] = (unsigned char*)lineAddr->lineBuffer;                        
    lines[1] = (noNext)? blankLine:(unsigned char*)(lineAddr->next->lineBuffer);
    lines[2] = ((noNext||noNextNext)? blankLine:(unsigned char*)(lineAddr->next)->next->lineBuffer);
    lines[3] = (lineAddr->prev==0UL)? blankLine:(unsigned char*)(lineAddr->prev->lineBuffer);
    //Print results
    printf("%08X %08X %08X %08X", lines[0], lines[1], lines[2], lines[3]);
    ...
}
```

Anything obvious about why this would not optimize correctly?

Comment: Why the hell are `next` and `prev` declared as `volatile`?!

Comment: Actually, if `next` is volatile, then the compiler isn't allowed to make assumptions of what `next` contains during optimization. So I'm guessing the volatile is some remaining debug code added when the OP was trying to dodge the original bug...?

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar these are declared volatile because they are modified within an ISR while the main process is only an accessor.

Comment: `volatile` is not a substitute for actual synchronization mechanisms. Although, as long as the other threads/processes are just reading that area of memory, you'll probably be fine.

Comment: Its a FIFO which should be acceptable per wikipedia, "The producer–consumer problem, particularly in the case of a single producer and single consumer, strongly relates to implementing a FIFO or a communication channel. The producer–consumer pattern can provide highly efficient data communication without relying on semaphores, mutexes, or monitors for data transfer. Use of those primitives can give performance issues as they are expensive to implement. Channels and Fifo's are popular just because they avoid the need for end-to-end atomic synchronization"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This bug is 2+ years old. I have confronted with it both with GCC ARM and GCC AVR compilers. It occures when you try to assign a value to array element by index or to element of structure. As far as I am  concerned the only solution is to reduce optimisation level to `-O1` or even to `-O0`

Comment: -1. This is not a bug, since the code in question exhibits undefined behaviour. Thus, the compiler is not required to produce any particular behaviour.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar  Should this really be -1?  Resolving code bug did not remove error.

Comment: @Max Can you provide details?  Are you saying that I could see this every time I do foo[i] = 0UL;?

Answer (score 4):

I could imagine that this might happen because

```
 bool noNextNext = (lineAddr->next)->next==0UL;
```

invokes UB if `lineAddr->next == NULL`. The fact that this line is called unconditionally might perhaps make the optimizer assume that `lineAddr->next` will never be `NULL`

Comment: Good catch, I have implemented this check with no success in resolving the issue.